# Is there a JavaScript equivalent to css/sass

Tags: javascript

I have recently begun using SASS.
It is amazing with partials, including them into the file then outputting all of your css to a single minified sheet.

Is there anything similar to this that can replicate these features for JavaScript files?

Comment: You mean like CoffeeScript? Or Browserify?

Comment: look into "build tools", require.js, etc, though with js, you can kinda use  it's parts from other parts anyway, so it's not going to be as big as a payoff as it is with purely declarative, often-repetitive code like css.

Comment: What specific features for javascript are you looking for?  I can't see how partials is an interesting feature for javascript so your question depends entirely upon what features you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Late reply, but I figure I can go ahead and answer in case anybody's like me and stumbled upon this page while googling a similar question.

There are a lot JavaScript compilers out there - Babel, CoffeeScript, YUI Compressor, and Closure to name a few.

What I ended up doing – and what's probably closer to what you're wanting to do – is  installing Gulp with the concat plugin. This [tutorial](https://travismaynard.com/writing/getting-started-with-gulp) walks you through the process of installing both those things very easily.